# Execute jar in Java Eclipse Maven before goals

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

How can I execute a Java jar file in Eclipse Maven before clean verify goals?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need that? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: I am using cucumber project and I want to generate feature_cucumber.feature file (automatically filled from Jira system), before mvn clean install command. Also I have tried to use @Before annotations and generate file but cucumber does not read feature file first.

Comment: How are you creating the the feature file at the moment? I assume via running an exectuable jar file which produces that? If so best is to create a Maven Plugin and integrate that into your build ...but from my point of view that sounds wrong cause you are generating test scenarios outside your current build structure. I would checkin those files with my source code...and run the build on that....?

Comment: First step I retrieve scenarios from API(Zapi Zephyr) Jira within jar and after that I run cucumber project. I will try to make a maven plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should [write a maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) for that and bind it to the pre-clean phase.